# PHP Web App to run Console SUDO Commands (Deciding how to do it)

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, command-line-interface

My company have a cloud dedicated server, hosted in google cloud, running centos 7 with apache2, php5.5 and mariadb running.

The webserver is running a private application for business clients and companys. Every client has his own database and subdomain, so they, and their own clients can access his applicacion going to http://theirname.example.net/

I've created an interactive command line script for client creation. It creates user and secure password, ftp custom folder, create mysqldatabase and populate it with a sql file, create subdomains and other thing. Also i've made another version of this script with no user interaction, receiving parameters as the client name via command line arguments ( /path-to/script.sh usertocreate mysqluser mysql pass).

So, here is the deal, i want to create a web interface, password protected, just available for my company IP address, this interface should be able to run these SH scripts (not the interactive ones) with sudo permissions.

I was thinking on create a subserver in other port (like http://example.org:2501) using another instance of apache (or other webserver) which runs with a specified user with sudo permissions enables only in the neccesary folders.

Before doing anything, i've created a PHP script which runs commands to console, and tried to run SUDO commands with that. Allowing apache user to sudoers list (just to make it work during develop). I could run these scripts from my web app without SUDO permissions, but they where not working at 100% (since some commands require SUDO). When i try with sudo i receive a code 127 error responde (permission problem).

I stopped there and decided to investigate the best way to do this.

I have full control of the server machine. Apache2 and everything normal is running well. (mariadb, proftpd with  passive mode active -100 ports added- )

SELINUX is DISABLED. Firewalld Running

SSH is available for use

I can install another webserver in another port to accomplish this. If a lot of HTTPD configurations should be changed to accomplish this, i will preffer to install another webserver

I can also install any 3rd party software.

I'm a PHP Developer with low experience in other programming languages, if it's necesary to invoke any other programming language to do this (maybe like Python) i would love some docummentation links

Access to this web application would be limited only to my company's static ip address and will be protected

Any thoughts/ideas ? Thanks in advance
PS: If someone want to edit my text and add some colours and format, edition will be aprovved

**EDIT TLDR:** I want to run another httpd in another with a webapi. This webapi should can run console commands as SUDO. Access to this webserver will be limited to my company's IP. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it and i want opinions. Also, i'm not pretty sure if its possible to run sudo commands from php without any trouble.

Comment: Please be succinct,  who i the world has time to read the book you posted.  What exactly is what you need to do, what is the expected output?

Comment: Probably much too broad of a question here.  My advice is that if you are using that cloud, then go all the way and use the cloud to it's fullest capability.  Don't have a bunch of vhosts all on the same server with that  being the same server that your admin application also runs on.   Get to the point where you can spawn individual resources for individual clients and pass all the set up data to you resource instances when instantiating them.  Focus your admin application on orchestration of instantiating these resources.  This way you can isolate resources for each account.

Comment: @datelligent TLDR: I want to run another httpd in another port with a webapi. This webapi should can run console commands as SUDO. Access to this webserver will be limited to my company's IP

Comment: @MikeBrant We are too small for that. I'm limited to 1 (max 2) servers running